# Qt6 - QComboBox applying style(sheet) to one specific item

Tags: c++, qtstylesheets, qcombobox, qt6

In a QComboBox, I have an item list.
One of this item is the default value (whatever the item currenlty selected).

[image]

For example, here, the current selected item is "INST IN", but the default value is "ALL" for this combobox.

Currently, I am using cb->model()->item to call setForeground, setBackround and changing the font. But this disable the stylesheet.

Is there a way to acheive this using stylesheet only ?
(I have not seen any property available in QStandardItem for example).

or any other idea to "view" this default value ?

Regards,

Comment: I made my own delegate that uses qtextdocment and html model text. Then styling is easy!

Comment: Can you write a c++ or python example?